# Ubuntu Swappiness Default Confusion

Tags: ram, swap

I have a question about swappiness that I am not understanding at all.  I was finding that my workstation often swapped during VMware Internet downloads.  Someone in the VMWare community suggested I change my swappiness.  swappiness defaults to 60 that I am having a tough time understanding why this default was chosen. I am reading that a swappiness of 60 is good for Ubuntu running as a server.  I read that on this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq/#What_is_swappiness_and_how_do_I_change_it.3F

If 60 is good for a server, why set swappiness to a default of 60 for a desktop install? The page above even goes as far as to recommend a swappiness value of 10 instead of 60.  Why not simply make the default 10?  When I do change swappiness to 10, my performance issues I was noticing vanish.  Swap is not used at all as it was with it set to 60, and I never run out of memory while performing my typical tasks.  This is very confusing to new Ubuntu users, and this default honestly makes no sense to me.

Edit:

showing output from free below:

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          125Gi       7.1Gi        46Gi        24Gi        72Gi        93Gi
Swap:         488Gi          0B       488Gi
```

The issue with excessive swap usage only happens when I run VMware. Honsestly, I think it is a VMware memory leak related to disk usage. swap growing nonstop during disk usage make no logical sense to me.

```
$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
A17
```

This is the latest BIOS available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer...

You can view your current setting using the `terminal`, with `sysctl vm.swappiness`. You can observe your memory and swap usage with `free -h`.

In the simplest explanation, vm.swappiness sets the ratio of in-memory activity vs swap activity. Swap refers to the use of a swap partition, or a /swapfile. All computers need swap. The size of swap varies by system configuration and usage.

vm.swappiness values approaching 10 do less swapping, with more in-memory activity. This can be used in high-memory environments, or where swap latency negatively effects performance, as in Ubuntu Server environments.

vm.swappiness values approaching 80/90 do more swapping, with less in-memory activity. This can be used in low-memory environments, where the desire is to rely more on swap. Generally, adding more memory, is a better long term solution.

The default vm.swappiness value for Ubuntu Desktop installs is 60. This strikes a good balance for typical users and configurations.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information.  Memory is the absolute cheapest upgrade anyone can make to hardware and provides the most bang for the buck.  For a laptop install, swappiness of 60 may make sense.  For a desktop (and especially in my case) 60 was a very poor setting.  I agree with the link I provided that recommended a value of 10.  For a desktop, low memory should be the exception and not the norm.

Comment: @Dryne vm.swappiness doesn't matter if it's a laptop or desktop... and the setting really depends on the amount of ram/swap/system usage. Setting vm.swappiness too low, in a low memory configuration, can also cause problems. Edit your question and show me `free -h`. re: *"For a desktop, low memory should be the exception and not the norm"*... really depends on the current memory configuration, and the user's budget.

Comment: My workstation has plenty of memory.  My issues only happen when I use VMware.  I think this software has the issue.

Comment: @Dryne That swap is insane. Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer or motherboard.

Comment: Dell Precision T7600

Comment: @Dryne I'd check if you have the latest VMware. If so, I'd contact the VMware Support folks.

Comment: Thank you.  These are the logical next steps.  I already posted all of this on the VMware community forum.  I do not have a support contract with VMware.  I agree that this is VMware's issue.

Comment: @Dryne  Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete. Also check out https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln288636/how-to-identify-and-resolve-memory-issues-on-precision-desktop-workstations?lang=en